# On using letters as unique identifiers

Tags: mysql

Creating a table of codes/abbreviations, each with a unique combination of case Sensitive letters. Is it ok to skip using an integer id and use them for foreign key checkups?
Or would there be issues I'm unaware of?

Comment: Should be fine as long as the abbreviations aren't too long. I'm not sure the case-sensitive part is a good idea, though.

Comment: @Wrikken: I don't seem to be able to use varchar fields for foreign keys

Comment: @Moak - varchar should be perfectly acceptable as foreign keys, can you post your table definitions?

Comment: @Moak: that could have something to do with not the _exact_ same column definition (length,charset,collation maybe).

Comment: Or not having an index on the foreign column of course, all the usual FK suspects apply (and MySQL still should have more descriptive error messages about those).

Comment: @Wrikken: I had an error 105, which i thought had to do with varchar but it was not related and solved now, you are right, the varchar index works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not generally an issue when working with relatively static data such as a country or a language table, keyed on country_code or language_code. I'd certainly not bother with an integer id there.

But if it's a table that regularly has extra data inserted, it's normally easier to work with an integer id, especially an autoincrement value.

Comment: Although, if there is a Natural key, you should use that: unless there is a very good reason not to.